# Assyncronous interaction using Sys WebForms PageRequestManager

Tags: asp.net, javascript, asynchronous, webforms, pagerequestmanager

I'm trying to display a panel to the user when an asynchronous call is made, but only if that happend from a specific call.

using the normal "get control" script I have mine like:

```
function pageLoad() {

    try {
        var manager = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
        manager.add_endRequest(OnEndRequest);
        manager.add_beginRequest(OnBeginRequest);
    }
    catch (err) { }
}

function OnBeginRequest(sender, args) {
    //alert('Start\n\n' + sender + '\n\n' + args);
    var p = document.getElementById('ajaxLoadingPanel');
    p.style.visibility = 'visible';
    p.style.display = 'inline';
}

function OnEndRequest(sender, args) {
    //alert('End\n\n' + sender + '\n\n' + args); 
    var p = document.getElementById('ajaxLoadingPanel');
    p.style.visibility = 'hidden';
    p.style.display = 'none';
}
```

but my question is **How do I know the methods of sender and args?**

I went [through the MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383809.aspx) and they talk nothing about the methods we can use, and there is no intellisence in VS2008 for this part...

any ideas? I want to get a list of methods and properties for both sender and args that I can use of this javascript API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This documentation is helpful:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398976.aspx

It has a table of all the events on PageRequestManager and what their event args are. Then the event args documents their properties, etc. The sender is always the PageRequestManager.

Answer (score 0):

Debug in ScriptDebugger and find out the contents of sender and args 
you can identify that which control has caused the postback

Answer (score 0):

To know which element caused postback, you can use `args.get_postBackElement().id`.